# Android: Download Manager

Tags: android, google-play

I want to implement a solution where I want to catch the  `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED` intents from the Android Market App i.e after the download of the app. The android Market app uses the default Download Manager and the download manager on the completion of the download sends such an intent, however I have not been able to capture it,I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.lytsing.org/archives/135.html) and please refer to [this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/docs/#ContentProvider_for_download_UI) to have more details on how market app uses Download Manager and for more information on Download Manager refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). Please do suggest me a way to catch those intents.

**EDIT**
This is what I am using for my Broadcast Reciever

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER">
</uses-permission>


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver 
        android:name=".DownloadReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS"
        android:exported="true">

         <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED">
            </action>
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
  </application>
```

Comment: Should work, provided that you declare the BroadcastReceiver in your manifest. You should post your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got everything right except the name of the action in the intent filter.  Note the `DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` instead of `DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED`

```
    <receiver 
        android:name=".DownloadReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/download_icon" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

This worked for me.  You do not need to register the receiver in code, this will listen even when your app isn't running.

Answer (score 1):

First register the reciever

```
registerReceiver(onComplete, 
new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

And set a BroadcastReciever to capture the event.

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            // run your action here
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes but still I cant catch the broadcast

Comment: are you downloading using the DownloadManager()? Also, if you develop building on the DownloadManager(), you're restricting yourself to version 2.3, you might want to consider using AsyncTask, so you could download in background and will be supported in 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Probabily your receiver is declared with lower priority than the registered for the Market application. Try to use *IntentFilter.setPriority()* or declare the priority on XML [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)