# Is there anyway I can use a BroadcastReceiver to catch DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an android application which is related to security. It is about scanning an application after it is downloaded from android market.

Is there anyway I can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to catch `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`?

I checked a couple of article but at time now the api's are hidden. Is there anyway I can use reflection method or something like to do this?

Comment: What do you mean the APIs are hidden? `DownloadManager` is available for API 9+, e.g. Android 2.3+.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974836/android-download-manager

Comment: I use the above example, Intent (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) is not fired when the application is downloaded completely.. I dont know why intent is not fired. my code is                                      <receiver android:name=".Reciever">
   <intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Comment: This is only fired if `DownloadManager` is used to download apk, not via Market.

Comment: is there anyway I can catch the intent for market app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this example

you need to use downloadManager class which is available in api 9 or above which calls a broadcast receiver on completion.

http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/